# Cannot extend partition after failed bootcamp install

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I got an error while trying to install Windows 10 on my Mid 2014 Macbook Pro via Bootcamp Assistant.

The error occurred whilst partitioning the disk: **Your disk could not be partitioned. An error occurred while partioning the disk**.

I'd set the partitions to be equal sizes, 250GB each.

I followed a *fix* that involves restarting into single user mode and running `/sbin/fsck -fy` but that didn't do anything to help.

I'm now left with a mac partition that's 250GB and free space that's 250GB, but cannot extend the main partition into the free space:
[image: Free space]

If I click partition and remove the freespace and extend the *Macintosh HD* volume I get this error: **The provided Core Storage logical volume has an incorrect size.**
[image: Core Storage incorrect size]

I'm happy to give up on bootcamp and installing Windows 10, but I'd like my harddisk back!!!

Answer (score 1):

Apple's Bootcamp is intended to be the beginning and end for where you handle partitioning. You can try opening Bootcamp Assistant and see if they will let you recover your space from here. I know I have done this before.

I've also run into the same problem with Disk Utility when it comes to Bootcamp partitions.